# Escaping Bootstrap Modals from wrapping div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that contains tile-divs. Within each tile-div is a div that contains content displayed within that tile and a div containing hidden modal content that is triggered onclick. **For CMS purposes the modal needs to be contained within the same div as the tile-div's content but display over the entirety of the page.**

The issue I'm having is the modal can't escape the tile-div to cover the whole page. It seems stuck within the tile-div container.

I've created a bootply example here: http://www.bootply.com/wtIPZuNXKY

HTML:

```
<div class="nopadding carousel-row">
  <div class="carousel-row-inner">

    <div class="gallery-cell" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">
      <div class="cell-details">
        <div class="cell-title">
          <h3>Cell title</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse vel.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!--gallery-cell-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

          </div>
    <!--tile-->

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 666;
}
.carousel-row-inner {
  font-size: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px auto;
  overflow: visible;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  -ms-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
  width: 242px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

JS

```
$('.gallery-cell').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $('#myModal').addClass('out');
});
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: The jquery code there for [onclick] is not being executed. the click happening there is due to the data-target attributes,

Comment: what is your expected behaviour. modal need to not get closed / modal need to be displayed inside the cell detail block !

Comment: I'd like for the modal to display atop the entire page despite being placed within a container div.

Comment: Move the modal to top. Check my answer below

Comment: @venkat - cant move modal, it needs to be bundled into the tile itself for CMS purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below is the `Bootply` URL

```js
    $('.gallery-cell').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      $('#myModal').addClass('out');
    });
```

```css
.carousel-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 666;
}
.carousel-row-inner {
  font-size: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px auto;
  overflow: visible;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  -ms-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
  width: 242px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nopadding carousel-row">
  <div class="carousel-row-inner">

    <div class="gallery-cell" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">
      <div class="cell-details">
        <div class="cell-title">
          <h3>Cell title</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse vel.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!--gallery-cell-->

          </div>
    <!--tile-->
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/2tzG8dK3ps

Comment: As explained, I need the modal to be bundled into the tile div for CMS purposes. Appreciate the help tho!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16974130)

Comment: @fordprefect: Added the Code

Comment: @Venkatraman thanks. This looks good but could you also include an explanation

Answer (score -1):

The answer was simply: `$('#myModal').appendTo('body');`

Comment: You are searching DOM which is under div.carousel-row-inner, there is no use case to open two modal at the same time. In general modal need to be unique for the page.